# Parsing JSON Array with JSON OBJECT

Tags: java, android, json

I have some JSON with the following structure:

```
{"cit": [
    "ALL",
    "Aceh Barat",
    "Aceh Besar",
    "Aceh Jaya",
    "Aceh Selatan",
    "Aceh Tengah",
    "Aceh Timur",
    "Aceh Utara"]}
```

i have try to parsing my json like this :

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
JSONArray city=jsonObject.getJSONArray("cit");

for (int j=0; j < city.length(); j++){
    JSONObject cit = city.getJSONObject(j);
    String kot = cit.toString(j);

    kota.add(kot);
}
```

on post execute :

```
ArrayAdapter<String> SpinnerKota = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Pencarian.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, kota);
spin_kota.setAdapter(SpinnerKota);
```

but nothing happen, is there any wrong with my code? i hope someone can help me to solve my problem.

Comment: How do you know nothing's happening?  Are you getting some kind of stack?  Are you not getting expected output?  (The snippet you posted doesn't indicate if you're going to get output one way or another.)

Comment: use this   `String kot=city.get(j)`

Comment: in my spinner it will show as : [
        "ALL",
        "Aceh Barat",
        "Aceh Besar",
        "Aceh Jaya",
        "Aceh Selatan",
        "Aceh Tengah",
        "Aceh Timur",
        "Aceh Utara"] and i think this is not true

Comment: @AoyamaNanami the spinner will show the above, because that is what is there in the json. What's wrong with it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"cit": [ // json array cit
"ALL",  // index 0 is ALL
```

Also there is no json object inside json array cit. So you don't need this `JSONObject cit = city.getJSONObject(j)`.

Change

```
  String kot = cit.toString(j);
```

To

```
  String kot =  (String) city.get(j);
```

Use the below

```
      JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("myjson string");
      JSONArray city=jsonObject.getJSONArray("cit");
      for(int i=0;i<city.length();i++)
      {
            String cities = (String) city.get(i);
            Log.i("All Cities",cities);
            kota.add(cities);
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this

```
    JSONArray json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL);

JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject(0);

JSONArray city  = c.getJSONArray("cit");    

for (int j=0; j < city.length(); j++){

    String kot = cit.get(j);

    kota.add(kot);
}
```

Comment: Mere code is not an answer. Please explain to OP what's wrong with his code.

Answer (score 0):

```
Object obj = yourJsonResult;
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
JSONArray msg = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("cit");
Iterator<String> iterator = msg.iterator();

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(iterator.next());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it as following code this is tested

```
String jsonSource="{'cit': ['ALL','Aceh Barat','Aceh Besar','Aceh Jaya','Aceh Selatan','Aceh Tengah','Aceh Timur','Aceh Utara']}";
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(jsonSource);
        JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("cit");         
        int length = jsonArray.length();
        String [] cities = new String [length];
        if (length > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                cities[i] = jsonArray.getString(i);
            }
        }
        //to check we can print our string array
        for (int i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
            Log.d("JSON parsing ",cities[i]);               
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Mere code is not an answer. Please explain to OP what's wrong with his code.